# Groovy: String to integer array

Tags: groovy

Im coding in Groovy and I have a string parameter "X" which looks like this:

```
899-921-876-123
```

For now i succesfully removed the "-" from it by

```
replaceAll("-", "")
```

And now I want to divide this String into separete numbers - to an array, like (8,9,9...) to make some calculations using those numbers. But somehow I cannot split() this String and make it an Integer at the same time like that:

```
assert X.split("")
def XInt = Integer.parseInt(X)
```

So then when Im trying something like:

```
def  sum = (6* X[0]+ 5 * X[1] + 7 * X[2])
```

I get an error that "Cannot find matching method int#getAt(int). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists." or "Cannot find matching method int#multiply(java.lang.String). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method " if im not converting it to Integer...

Any idea how can I just do calculations on separate numbers of this string?

Answer (score 3):

```
def X = '899-921-876-123'
def XInt = X.replaceAll(/\D++/, '').collect { it as int }
assert XInt == [8, 9, 9, 9, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 1, 2, 3]
assert 6* XInt[0]+ 5 * XInt[1] + 7 * XInt[2] == 6* 8+ 5 * 9 + 7 * 9
```

the `replaceAll` removes all non-digits
the `collect` iterates over the iterable and converts all elements to `int`s
a `String` is an iterable of its characters

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but the "X" is a parameter and could be dynamically updated, the number I gave you is an example. So when I do:   def X = X.replaceAll(/\D++/, '').collect { it as int } it gives me an error "The method collect on class java.lang.Object is not permitted" And How can I do any calculations on it after?

Comment: `is not permitted` sounds strange, are you trapped in some sandbox? What I gave you was plain Groovy without any sandbox. `String#replaceAll` gives you back a `String` where the replacement was done and on which you should be able to call `collect` if no sandbox prevents it. Or is your `X` not actually a `String`? What does `X.getClass()` give you? I adapted my example to take into account that `X` is already present as parameter and showed you an example of how to calculate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Given you already just have a string of numbers:

```
"123"*.toLong() // or toShort(), toInteger(), ...
// ===> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: A `split` is not necessary, a `String` is an iterable of its characters, so you can directly use `collect`. Converting to `long` is a bit overkill if you only have single digits and using the Groovy magic with `as ...` is better anyway. ;-)

Comment: @Vampire Thanks, changed it

Answer (score 1):

If found @cfrick approach the most grooviest solution.

This makes it complete:

```
def n = "899-921-876-123".replaceAll("-", "")
print n*.toInteger()
```